# Stripe: who's in charge of updating expired card?

Tags: stripe-payments

In Stripe subscriptions, when a card is expired, does Stripe contact the user and let enter a new card on Stripe end, or is it all done by the application?

Is there a Stripe members area that users can use to manage their stripe stuff, like PayPal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you are. Stripe does not offer a client area for such updates at the moment. There is a WordPress plugin that we developed which allows self-service credit card updates and integrates with Stripes dunning email workflow.

It is a paid product and can be found at [www.Cloudswipe.net](https://www.Cloudswipe.net).

Answer (score 5):

In a lot of cases, Stripe will automatically update the card without any action required from either the merchant or the customer: https://stripe.com/blog/smarter-saved-cards

That said, customers never interact with Stripe directly. If you want to provide a way for your customers to update their saved card, you will need to collect the new card's information (using [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js)), and [update the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer) with the new card's token in the `source` parameter.

Comment: Great, thanks very much. The blog link is very helpful also.

Answer (score 1):

however,my webhook never got the 'customer.source.updated' event, and lots of my customers just stop recurring billing plan after their card expired. i doubt the 'Smarter saved cards' is working correctly or just some wrong with my settings.